# SVN: accessing the history of mergeinfo

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

How can I access the history of the mergeinfo property in SVN?

I tried to play a bit with `Tortoise` but I couldn't find any solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'include merged revisions' checkbox on the log dialog doesn't do it for you?

Comment: The problem is that someone deleted all the mergeinfo and now I would like to edit mergeinfo property manually to restore the information of already merged changesets. But to do it I should read the previous values of the mergeinfo properties. Or I don't know..

Comment: Mergeinfo is a property, so just "update to revision" to get to a specific historic revision and the look at the properties. Copy, , update back to HEAD, paste.. job done.